# Beginner: syntax error before int main ()

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a Hello World program but am getting the error

```
./ex1.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `(`
./ex1.c: line 3: `int main (int argc, char *argv[])'
```

or

```
./ex1.c: 3: ./ex1.c: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

or

```
./ex1.c:3: unknown file attribute: i
./ex1.c:4: parse error near `}'
```

The weird thing is I've run this same program before and had no issues.

Not sure if these issues are related but the problem happened after I installed Valgrind to run exercise 4 in Learn C The Hard Way. I received an error that said permission denied which I fixed using `chmod +x`. Then all my `.c` files needed permission which they had not before. I then did `chmod -R 0777` for the directory with all of my .c practice files. So the permission problem is fixed but then the error above started. They may be completed unrelated but wanted to include just in case.

Comment: If you have problems with *code*, then please post it. Otherwise, how do you expect us to help you? All I can tell you from this is that you have an unexpected `(` in line 3.

Comment: But from this I can tell he is running the `.c` file, and that the shell is complaining about the C syntax...

Comment: You *don't* want your `*.c` files to have execute permissions, and you rarely want *anything* to have 777 permissions (which give read-write-execute permission to everyone on the system).

Comment: This was so good as a canonical duplicate target because it explained your reasoning and how you got this problem, that I decided to add some more error messages from other shells.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't *run* a `.c` file just by using `./ex1.c`; you have to *compile* it into a runnable program first.

Assuming you have a Linux/OS X machine, use `gcc -Wall ex1.c -o ex1` to compile it (or, more simply, `make ex1`). Then you can `./ex1` to run the program.

Comment: I realized what I was doing wrong. I had used make but was still leaving .c after ./ex1. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

After you compile the program by using make "your program name" (like make mario in this case), then just use ./"your program name" (this case ./mario). DO NOT add .c when running the program.

Comment: These are instructions for using Makefiles, which is probably not related to the syntax error @MParker has.

Comment: A similar answer was given _3 years_ ago.